# Is there an NSNotification for phone call status

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

Is there an NSNotification we can observe for when the device is on/off the phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NotificationCenter` doesn't send out any notifications abou this, but take a look at the `CTCallCenter` class introduced in iOS 4. It has a `callEventHandler` property that you can assign a block of code to, and gets called with call state info.

There is a limitation in that the handler only gets called when your app is in the foreground (or being taken out of the foreground when a call comes in), but it tells you if the user is dialing (`CTCallStateDialing`), receiving a call (`CTCallStateIncoming`), answering/connecting (`CTCallStateConnecting`) or hanging up on a call (`CTCallStateDisconnected`).

Comment: Thanks Arash. That pointed me in the right direction. Based on that document, "If your application is active when a call event takes place, the system dispatches the event to your handler immediately...While it is suspended, your application does not receive call events."  I'm curious if the states they are talking about are specific to Application states; suspended is different than background. Best to give it a try and find out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one that I'm aware of, but if the issue is that you want to know about the change in status bar then you can observe `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` (as documented towards the bottom of the [UIApplication documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and get a new rect from the relevant userInfo whenever a change occurs.