# iPhone application starting problem

Tags: iphone

In my application if im middle of something in my app and i want application should exit(not go in background) when pressing central black round button on iPhone.

Secondly if application is in middle of something and if call comes then it should start from same point.

How can i do that.

Comment: yes actually i dont want to start application on pressing central button. i want if my application is processing and somebody press central button it should exit it.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415480/iphone-application-starting-problem/7415555#7415555

Comment: You just linked this same page......

Comment: I tried to link the comment. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: i got that answer but im wondering guys is this nice practice to exit application when pressing central black button and start application from splash screen again. i.e. from starting. just need ur valuable suggestions:-)

Answer (score 1):

If what is you need is your application to start on pressing the Home button on the iPhone, then its not possible. The iPhone has a single button which is used for specific purposes. You cannot override the button action to start your app. And even if you find some ingenious way to do it, Apple are certainly not going to approve it.

Comment: Yes i think i was not able to make u understand wot i want to say. plz check my question updated now

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks application starts from starting pressing central button. wot if call comes it will start from the same point? second is this good practice to exit application pressing central button.? just need ur suggestion:-) will accept ur answer in a moment

Comment: i think this will close the application even when a call comes in..

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is not clear at all. If what youre trying to do is load an app according to the status you last closed it (Whether you press the home button or interrupted with a call). Your app will go back to its regular status naturally in iOS 4 after a phone call or if it wasnt closed from the multifunctional bar. However if you want to force your app to start from the beginning on any launch expect from when your coming back from a call the following may help:

you can determine whether a call is incoming while youre app is open using `CTCallCenter`. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604459/is-there-an-nsnotification-for-phone-call-status).

Using the delegate method `applicationDidEnterBackground:` you can check whether a call is incoming or not and then decide whether you want to close your application.

**EDIT**:

I am not sure this will work as i am not on my computer but give it a try. Insert the following code in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method:

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

if ([callCenter.currentCalls count] == 0)
    exit(0);
```

You will need to add the CoreTelephony framework to your project and delegate.h file.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks KDaker i agree with ur point . Now in applicationDidEnterBackground: method how can i check if application responding to call or to button press? this is the issue.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    
    
    CTCallCenter *callCenter=[CTCallCenter alloc];
                //handle disconnect
    if ([callCenter.currentCalls count] == 0)
    {
      
    }
    exit(0);

}
I did this because when call comes i want my applcation to go background and if central black button of iphone press it quits. m i right? just confirm

Comment: The exit(0) should be inside the if argument not outside.. The way you wrote you are doin he opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Add **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** in your info.plist

> **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend**
>
> UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (Boolean - iOS) specifies that the
>   application should be terminated rather than moved to the background
>   when it is quit. Applications linked against iOS SDK 4.0 or later can
>   include this key and set its value to YES to prevent being
>   automatically opted-in to background execution and application
>   suspension. When the value of this key is YES, the application is
>   terminated and purged from memory instead of moved to the background.
>   If this key is not present, or is set to NO, the application moves to
>   the background as usual.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 4.0 and later.

Comment: But if call comes then it will go to background or exit? because i want to go it background if call comes

Answer (score 0):

first one you mentioned was not clear.What you need actually?
The second one can be done by cache the page you last visited and then navigate to or place that page when applicationDidBecomeActive.The applicationDidBecomeActive in appDelegate will execute whenever ypur application become active

Comment: how can i do that. n for first question plz check my updated question

Comment: To exit from your app instead of going to background use exit(0) in applicationDidEnterBackground delegate

Comment: ok but if call comes then even app will exit? if yes then u suggested why how can i use that? plz tell me code