# iOS call status tracking and get phone number

Tags: iphone

I am making a voicemail app for iOS. In this app i want two things-

1. Call status - If i called someone then how will i get the status of his i.e. it is busy or not reachable or switch off or call disconnected.
2. Phone no - If i get the status of call then how can i send voicemail on another user phone. Can i get the another user's phone no.

This is not an app to app application. I am getting caller by making him register through my app BUT by which mean i can get the number of the user who called??? Does apple provide this type of permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

- [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604459/is-there-an-nsnotification-for-phone-call-status)
- [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4/3320212#3320212)

For your second question, there is no way for you to retrieve the caller's phone number. CoreTelephony only gives you limited access to the information such as a unique identifier for your calls and call state. To get more information, you're definitely going to have to use some low-level functions and jailbreak which means it will not be accepted into the Appstore.